# Network two vm's on one host machine whether on or off the network domain

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualization

I have a corporate network with the ip addressing range of 192.168.0.x

I have a host machine (a mac) which when on the network gets it's ip's from dhcp.

On the host machine i have 2 Virtualbox windows VM's that i need to have running all the time and they need to talk to each other as one is a server and one is a client. However, the client also needs to act as a normal machine on the network and so at the moment is running in bridged mode.

My problem is that if i have both VM's running in bridged network mode, when the user is off the network (at home for example), they still need the two windows VM's to be able to talk to each other.

Any ideas how i can achieve the desired setup on or off the network?

Comment: The question is a little vague. Do you mean the host is a laptop that travels off the physical network or are you asking for help setting up a vpn tunnel so the VM's can be accessed remotely from home?

Answer (score 2):

Just add an additional NIC to each machine with another IP range. They can then talk to each other on that interface